# Adding 301 redirect to a php file

Tags: redirect

I need to add to my site some links which I have redirected using a file named redirect.php with this code:

```
<? header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
$linkid = $_GET['linkid'];
if ($linkid == "1234") {$link = "http://advertiserlink.co.uk/";}
header("Location: $link");
exit();
?>
```

I'd like to ask if this correct from the 301 redirect point of view and Google won't find the link I'll place in my text: for example http://mysite.co.uk/redirect.php?linkID=1234. I have also disallowed the redirect.php in my robots.txt.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It works on my computer

```
<?php
    $link = ($_GET['link'] == '1234) ? 'http://my1234.example.com/' : 'http://example.com/';
    header('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
    header('Location: ' . $link);
    exit();
?>
```

Comment: Yes, it works here as well, but I am not sure if Google will "accept" the 301 redirection and will ignore this: http://mysite.co.uk/redirect.php?linkID=1234 Thank you!